# Shifting bytes in ARM into a temp register using MOVZ and MOVK

Tags: arm, hex, mov, byte-shifting

I am doing a problem for my computer architecture class, but I am running into a weird issue with byte shifting. I have tried several different methods, but so far nothing has changed how my bytes are shifted into x3.The general gist is I am not allowed to use MOV, so we have to split our hex into 4 byte increments. I use MOVZ to clear out my temporary register and attempt to move in 0x0F0F, for example, but instead I get 0xF0F.[Image of my code working with 0x5's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No8wL.png)
It works fine when I try to move in 0x555555555555, but when I try to move in any hex starting with 0's, they get deleted/dissapear on me. [Image of code Removing my first 0's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b4Ll.png)

I have tried using just MOVK, I have tried flipping the numbers themselves and the way I shift them in, but the system does not want to accept initial 0's.

Thoughts? Is this an environment issue or am I misunderstanding how these tools work?

Comment: This is just the result of the debugger (or whatever this is) not printing leading zeroes right, it doesn't mean anything